# Failing to share content on Messenger via FBSDKShareLinkContent

Tags: ios, facebook, share, facebook-messenger

I'm trying to add the ability to share a text + URL on my iOS app via `Facebook Messenger`, but it keeps failing.

- What happens is that Messenger is getting opened, but with no content (both text and url are missing).
- Also, tried to remove the URL - same result.
- In addition, the Send button on Messenger stays disabled no matter what (even after choosing recipient and adding text).
- I get no error from Messenger

Maybe someone has any idea? My app is still in Sandbox, maybe that's the cause?

This is the code I use:

```
FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [FBSDKShareLinkContent new];
content.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:<URL>];
content.contentDescription = @"testing...";
[FBSDKMessageDialog showWithContent:content delegate:self];
```

Comment: Not possible. Prefilling text is not allowed by Facebook Platform Policy

Comment: @WizKid - got you - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So as mentioned by @WizKid, it seems that pre filling text is not allowed by Facebook Platform Policy.